# In the interval$ (-2\pi, 0)$, the function$ f(x) = \sin (1/x^3)$ changes its sign how many times?

Tags: trigonometry

options given are :
(A) Never changes sign
(B) Changes sign only once
(C) Changes sign more than once, but a finite number of times
(D) Changes sign $\infty$ number of times

I have used google to draw the plot of $ f(x) = \sin (1/x^3)$ and my conclusion based on my intuition is (D)=$\infty$ no. of times.
[image]

But proper mathematical reasoning is what I require to support the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is $1$ at all points such that $\frac{1}{x^3}=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ $\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{1}{(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})^\frac{1}{3}}=g(k)$. Notice that $g(k)$ is in the interval $(-2\pi,0)$ for all sufficiently small $k$ (small as in negative but having large modulus) which shows that your initial function hits $1$ infinitely many times in your interval. You can similarly show that it is infinitely many times equal to $-1$. Now argue by continuity that it changes sign infinitely often.

Comment: A little elaboration could have helped me more. Although this is sufficient for me.

Comment: What have I not said?

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x$ changes of sign for $x \in \{k\pi ; k\in \mathbb Z\}$. Hence $\sin\left(1/x^3 \right)$ changes of sign for $x \in A=\{ \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}; k \in \mathbb N \}$. And the cardinality of $A \cap (-2\pi, 0)$ is infinite.

Comment: Still feeling awry with the answer as if a cloud of suspicion and doubt still hovering around. Can't tell you it is like the feeling of "there's going to be rain in the afternoon" thing that we have in our Indian rural places.

Comment: @Saradamani If you want suspicion to go away, just write a couple of equations like $1/x^3 = k \iff...$